# How to use the most updated state/value inside a 3rd party event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Given something like:

```
function MapControl() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useContext(CountriesContext)
  useEffect( () => {
    ThirdPartyApi.OnSelectCountry((country) => {
      setCountries([...countries, country])
    })
  })

  return (<ThirdPartyApi.Map />)
}
```

I have the problem that the call to `setCountries` doesn't work as expected, because the `countries` array is not updated from the context of the custom event handler provided by `ThirdPartyApi`.

What is a clean way to model this? It's possible to just have a local mutable array that I update in the event handler, but that wouldn't pick up any changes to `countries` from other components, so feels doomed to cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to modify your state using the latest value instead of capturing it from the stale closure:

```
function MapControl() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useContext(CountriesContext)

  useEffect( () => {
    ThirdPartyApi.OnSelectCountry((country) => {
      setCountries((prev) => [...prev, country])
    })

    return () => {
      // unregister event handler
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <ThirdPartyApi.Map />
  )
}
```

Also make sure to [specify your dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) for `useEffect()` so that you're not triggering your side-effect on every re-render. In this case, your side effect doesn't have any dependencies, so it should be empty `[]`.

Lastly, make sure to [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) your effect when the component unmounts. In this case you need to unregister your event handler within the returned callback from `useEffect()`.

Comment: Ah yeah I forgot about this feature; I ended up creating a new state in `MapControl`, setting that from the `OnSelectCountry` handler, and having another `useEffect` with dependency on my newly created state to eventually call `setCountries`, but this looks cleaner so I will use your suggestion instead. Much appreciated :)